# How to get WordPress theme name by custom URL

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to get WordPress theme name using API. I have tried this code but I want the same result using custom url:

```
function theme_list_function(){
    // Get a list of themes
    $list = wp_get_themes();
    // Return the value
    var_dump($list);
}
```

This code will return current WordPress theme list. I want theme list form a URL like xyz.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this using this code:

```
$target_site    = ""; // put your wordpress url here
$src            = file_get_contents( $target_site );
preg_match("/\<link rel='stylesheet'.*href='(.*?style\.css.*?)'.*\>/i", $src, $matches );

if( $matches ) {
    $style_href     = trim( $matches[1] );
    $style_src      = file_get_contents( $style_href );
    preg_match( "/\Theme Name:(.*?)\n/i", $style_src, $theme_name );

    $theme_name = str_replace(' ', '', $theme_name[1]);

    var_dump( $theme_name );

}
```